# How to Save Multiple files in One row in Sql with Spring boot and JPA

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I have an application Where I am saving a file in row of Mysql Database as Lob.Now  I got requirement as the user can upload multiple files and I have to save them in Database.So,It is possible to Update Multiple Files in One columns? If not So, how can I save them dynamically Because one user may upload 2 files other may upload 3 files and later on I should able to retrieve them as well(Currently I am  able retrieve since it is single file)

[Please image for see application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvSNs.png)

//Entity Class
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "`uploadfile`")
    private byte[] uploadfile;

Spring Boot Code to Save Single Now

//Controller

```
public SuccessPojo updatereport(@RequestParam("reportname") String reportname,
        @RequestParam(name = "uploadfile", required = false) MultipartFile uploadFile)
```

//Service Impl

```
public int storeFile(String reportname, MultipartFile file)
    ) {
        byte filedata[];
        if (file != null) {
            filedata = file.getBytes();
        } else {
            filedata = null;
        }
        return branchusermakerrepos.updatemakerreport(filedata, reportname);
```

}

JPA Query

```
          @Query("update Test k set k.uploadfile= :uploadfile where k.reportname= :reportname)
  int updatemakerreport(@Param("uploadfile")byte[] uploadfile@Param("reportname") String reportname);
```

Comment: using onetomay relationship between user and file may be a good choice

Comment: Yeah I was also thinking the same,So..It is not possible to Save multiple file in one column right?

Comment: It's not in one column, n files will be strored in n columns related to one record of user. Check `jpa onetomany` for more information.